# If I plan to run a stepwise multiple regression, should I examine VIF in the final model, or of all variables before using the stepwise approach?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, stepwise-regression, variance-inflation-factor

Suppose I have ten predictors that I want to use to predict Y. I plan to run a multiple regression using stepwise selection. My question is, should I assess colinearity in the final model (i.e., examine VIF of the variables that make it into the model)? Or should I first simply run a multiple regression with all ten variables and examine colinearity when all ten are in the model?

Comment: The first question is why you plan to use stepwise selection in the first place. [This superb answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/28500), among many others on this site, explains the substantial drawbacks. Please explain more about what you are trying to accomplish in your work; there is almost certainly a better solution than stepwise selection.

Comment: Okay, I am looking into Least Angle Regression as a model selection procedure. But this is a separate issue. I'm still hoping to get an answer to my original question: should I evaluate colinearity among all possible predictors or just those that make it into the model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the thread EdM recommends above because I think the critique it makes is the best answer to this question. Answering the specific question raised here is merely tinkering with a bad method, when the best way forward is to use a different one.

Comment: @mkt But this is an interesting question and in his comment, the OP says he is looking into LAR. So ... what to do? Maybe a new question is needed.

Comment: I voted to leave this open for now, but I could be convinced to change my mind.

Comment: @PeterFlom I'm fine with leaving open since your answer covers the stepwise problem and also addresses the interesting portion (+1). Would perhaps be nice for the LAR part to be edited into the question, but I'm not sure if that is best left to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments - if you plan to run stepwise regression, you should probably change your plans.

But, suppose (as you indicate in a comment) that you are going to use LAR. Then the question is whether looking at collinearity first is a good idea. I would say yes. Collinearity is going to affect the standard errors of your parameter estimates and that will affect all sorts of things. If there is substantial collinearity, then you might want to apply your variable selection method to a different model - such as ridge regression. Or you might want to remove one or more variables from the data set. Or something else.